# How do I write this for loop using an alternative variable?

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner and this is a class assignment. So, please just give me some pointers if you will. I need to find the answer but I am stuck. The instructions:

```
function exerciseTwo(){
  let count = 0;

  // In this exercise write your own for loop (you can look at the syntax above). 
  // It should loop 10 times.
  // You are given a variable called: count .
  // For each loop reassign count to the current value of count + 1 .


  //Please write your answer in the line above. 
  return count;
}
```

All of my possible answers that have returned with a failed run test:

```
for (let count = 0; count < 10; count++) {

     console.log ("count");
   }
```

```
for (let count = 0; count < 10; i++) {

     console.log ("count");
   }
```

In this one I thought I should create a few variables to help. And I knew that they probably would not work. But, in the spirit of trying.

```
function exerciseTwo(){
  let count = 0;
  let count = i;
  let i = 0
  // In this exercise write your own for loop (you can look at the syntax above). 
  // It should loop 10 times.
  // You are given a variable called: count .
  // For each loop reassign count to the current value of count + 1 .
   for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

     console.log ("i");
   }
```

Comment: must be `console.log (i);`

Comment: To print the value of a variable you don't need quotes around it. If you use quotes then you're printing a string (ie the literal thing you wrote)

Answer (score 1):

You could take `count` directly and use a `while` loop with a check if the value is smaller than 10.

The problem with your code is, you take for a nested scope a local variable `count`, which does not change the outer `count`.

```js
function x() {
    let count = 0;
    while (count < 10) ++count;
    return count;
}

console.log(x());
```

By looking to the [`for` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), you get fout parts of it

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
   statement
```

- *`initialization`*, is not needed here, because you have already a declared and initialized variable `count`, which is used in the `for` statement.
- *`condition`* is to check if a variable as a certain value. If resolves to `true` or is a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value, then the loopis going on.
- *`final-expression`* it to udate a loop dependent variable, but it can contain more than one expression. All above parts can contain more than one expression.
- *`statement`* is here an empty statement, just denoted with a semicolon `;`. Usually ther is one statement or a [block `{}` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), which is to group more than one statements.

```js
function x() {
    let count = 0;
    for (; count < 10; ++count) ;
    return count;
}

console.log(x());
```

Answer (score 0):

A few hints:

1) If you create two variables with the same name, the parser doesn't know which one you want to refer at, therefore it assumes you want to refer to the most inner variable. That means that `count` inside the `for` loop will refer to the variable used in the `for` loop. Using `i` to distinguish both variables is a good choice.

```
  let count = 0; // outer

  for(let count = 0; count < 10; count++) { // inner
    console.log("inner", count); // refers to the "inner" count
  }

  console.log("outer", count); // refers to the "outer" count
```

2) `"i"` is a string, it doesn't refer to a variable. `i` however refers to the variable, so

```
 console.log(i);
 console.log("i", i); // logs e.g. "i 0", which is really helpful if you log a lot of numbers
```

is way more useful.

3) the assignment clearly states that you have to assign `count` (`=`) the value of `count + 1`, why don't you just do that (in the loop)?

Comment: I did try that and it still did not pass the run test. Not sure why.

Comment: @MiMiiXV add some `console.log`s to see whats going on, and what value `count` has in the end.

Answer (score 0):

The first two attempts define `count` using `let` within the `for` loop, which is scoped to the `for` loop. In the last attempt `count` is defined outside of the `for` loop. In neither case is `count` actually incremented `count = count + 1`

```js
function getCount() {

  let count = 0;

  // In this exercise write your own for loop (you can look at the syntax above).
  // It should loop 10 times.
  // You are given a variable called: count .
  // For each loop reassign count to the current value of count + 1 .
  
  // we increment `count` here
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++, count += 1);

  //Please write your answer in the line above.
  return count;
}

console.log(getCount());

getCount()
```

Comment: *"In this exercise write your own for loop"* ... without copying it from an SO answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do this:

```
let count = 0; //variable is defined here just initialize it in the for loop
for (count = 0; count < 10; count++) {    
    console.log(count); //don't use count as a string ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**We are given the value of count and we are told that it needs to loop 10 times.**

```
let count = 0;
```

** Below we are stating that count is at 0 initially, then we need to write the condition that count is less than or equal to 9. Finally, we add an increment of one which puts the total count at 10.**

```
for(count = 0; count <= 9; count++) {
console.log(count);
}
```

, another alternative would be

```
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
count++;
}
```